# react xarrows not render properly when site load first time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, user-interface, web, user-experience

[When site load first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDfDC.png)
lines are not properly connect to given elements

[After reload page once](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXY1x.png) 
lines are properly connect to given elements

this is my diagram.js component

```
import React from "react";
import Xarrow, { Xwrapper } from "react-xarrows";
import './Diagram.css';

class Diagram extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
              lines:[
                    {       
                    start:"test3",
                    end:"test1" ,
                    color:'green',
                    path:'grid',
                    dashness:{ animation: 1 },
                    showHead:false
                    },
                    {       
                    start:"test3",
                    end:"test2" ,
                    color:'green',
                    path:'grid',
                    dashness:{ animation: 1 },
                    showHead:false
                    },
                    {       
                    start:"test3",
                    end:"test4" ,
                    color:'green',
                    path:'grid',
                    dashness:{ animation: 1 },
                    showHead:false        
                    },
                    {       
                    start:"test3",
                    end:"test5" ,
                    color:'green',
                    path:'grid',
                    dashness:{ animation: 1 },
                    showHead:false        
                    },
                    ]
            }
    }

    render(){
            return(
                    <Xwrapper>
                            <div className="bulma-col columns is-2 is-multiline is-mobile">

                                    <div className="column is-4">
                                    <img className="icon is-medium" src='' alt="test1" id="test1"/>
                                    <div>test1</div>
                                    </div> 
                                    
                                    <div className="column is-4"></div>

                                    <div className="column is-4">
                                            <img className="icon is-medium" src='' alt="test2" id="test2" />
                                            <div>test2</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="column is-4"></div>

                            
                                    <div className="column is-4">
                                            <img className="icon is-medium" src='' alt="test3" id="test3" />
                                            <div>test3</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="column is-4"></div>

                                    <div className="column is-4">
                                            <img className="icon is-medium" src='' alt="test4" id="test4" />
                                            <div>test4</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="column is-4"></div>
                                    
                                    <div className="column is-4">
                                            <img className="icon is-medium" src='' alt="test5" id="test5" />
                                            <div>test5</div>
                                    </div>
                                    {this.state.lines.map((line,i)=>(<Xarrow key={i} {...line} />))}
                            </div>
                    </Xwrapper>
            )
        
    }
}
export default Diagram;
```

I tried to figure a way to fix this bug. I tried to create lines in state. I googled this but have no any solution.can someone help me to figure this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used useXarrow react-xarrows hook and changed my code like this.My issue was fixed.But I don't know how,why and is it the best solution?

```
import React from "react";
import Xarrow, { useXarrow } from "react-xarrows";
import './Diagram.css';

const Diagram =()=>{
      const lines=[
               {       
                start:"test3",
                end:"test1" ,
                color:'green',
                path:'grid',
                dashness:{ animation: 1 },
                showHead:false
                },
                {       
                start:"test3",
                end:"test2" ,
                color:'green',
                path:'grid',
                dashness:{ animation: 1 },
                showHead:false
                },
                {       
                start:"test3",
                end:"test4" ,
                color:'green',
                path:'grid',
                dashness:{ animation: 1 },
                showHead:false        
                },
                {       
                start:"test3",
                end:"test5" ,
                color:'green',
                path:'grid',
                dashness:{ animation: 1 },
                showHead:false        
                },
      ]
      return(
            <div onLoad={useXarrow()} className="bulma-col columns is-2 is-multiline is-mobile">

                                <div className="column is-4">
                                <img className="icon is-medium" src='' alt="test1" id="test1"/>
                                <div>test1</div>
                                </div> 
                                
                                <div className="column is-4"></div>

                                <div className="column is-4">
                                        <img className="icon is-medium" src='' alt="test2" id="test2" />
                                        <div>test2</div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="column is-4"></div>

                        
                                <div className="column is-4">
                                        <img className="icon is-medium" src='' alt="test3" id="test3" />
                                        <div>test3</div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="column is-4"></div>

                                <div className="column is-4">
                                        <img className="icon is-medium" src='' alt="test4" id="test4" />
                                        <div>test4</div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="column is-4"></div>
                                
                                <div className="column is-4">
                                        <img className="icon is-medium" src='' alt="test5" id="test5" />
                                        <div>test5</div>
                                </div>
                                {lines.map((line,i)=>(<Xarrow key={i} {...line} />))}
        </div>
        )
}
export default Diagram;
```